# check whether a string contains a character in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare and see if a particular character exists in the string, but when i try to access the character which is in another string, its throws an error 'argument of type 'int' is not iterable'. How do i access the character from a string without causing the error?

```
    def lengthOfLongestSubstring(self, s: str) -> int:
        longStrLen = 0
        totalStrLen = len(s)

        holderString = ""
        holderString += s[0]
        longStrLen = 0

        for i in range(1,totalStrLen-1):

            if s[i] not in holderString:
                holderString += s[i]
            else:
                if longStrLen < len(holderString):
                    longStrLen = len(holderString)
                holderString = 0

        return longStrLen
```

```
TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable at Line 
if s[i] not in holderString:
```

Comment: `holderString = 0` You've reassigned holderString to an integer, and it's not a string any more.

Comment: Specifically when you check whether the character exists in the string, you set the whole holderstring to 0 when you encounter a duplicate letter. `cat` will run but `caaat` will not

Comment: Why is this a method? You don't use `self` anywhere in the body.

Comment: What exactly is the function supposed to do? It appears that you just want the index of the first repeated character.

Comment: @chepner I would assume due to the inclusion of `self` it's from a class, but for the [mcve], the asker (correctly) only provided the nonworking snippet of code

Comment: @G.Anderson It's not minimal if you can remove `self` without changing the behavior of the function.

Comment: @chepner, I disagree, I am able to reproduce the error in the OP with `lengthOfLongestSubstring(None, 'aaa')`, and I'd rather have this than have OP post the entire class with all functions and a main block. If you'd like to discuss further we can move to chat or ask the question on meta

Comment: @G.Anderson It doesn't matter *what* value you pass as the first argument; the body *never looks at it*. If `self` is relevant, we need the class. If it isn't relevant, you can reproduce the error with a function that doesn't take it as an argument.

Comment: @chepner again, I don't think you're wrong, _per se_, I just disagree. This is the minimum code required to reproduce the issue. The rest of the class is irrelevant, so I, for one, appreciate it not being included. I also don't have a problem with the unused arg being included as removing it is an easily missed step in posting a question, and doesn't impose a problem in helping fix the problem by its existence. Again, if this is a special concern of yours, I would recommend asking a question on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) to get a consensus rather than either of our opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is on this line:

```
holderString = 0
```

You reassigned the `holderString` variable to the integer 0. While strings can be iterated over, integers cannot. You attempt to iterate over the new integer on this line:

```
if s[i] not in holderString:
```

which causes the error.

There is a much better way to approach a function that returns the first repeated character though. Simply use the `index()` method:

```
def findChar(char, string):
    for c in string:
        if c == char: 
             return string.index(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you only need to count unique characters until you find the first duplicate. You can do that with a set.

```
def longest_substring(s: str) -> int:
    seen = set()
    for c in s:
        if c in seen:
            break
        seen.add(c)
    return len(seen)
```